# dictionary array value search using lambda

Tags: c#, linq, dictionary, lambda, linq-expressions

How do you search a dictionaries value which is an object using lambda expressions. (using the classes below)

```
Dictionary<int, House[]> houseDict = new Dictionary<int, House[]>();
```

Say there are 3 elements each with 10 houses.

How do I find a house/houses belonging to a customer based on the element e.g.

This is what I've got so far but dont know how to narrow down to the houseNumber

```
houseDict[0].Where(s => s.GetCustomer() == theCustomer)
```

this doesn't work -> `houseDict[0].SelectMany(s => s.GetHouseNumber()).Where(c => c.GetCustomer() == theCustomer);`

```
public class House
{
  private static int _instances = 0;
  private int houseNumber;
  private bool sold;
  private bool reserved;
  private bool free;

  private Customer customer;

  public House(int theHouseNumber)
  {
      houseNumber = theHouseNumber;
      sold = false;
      reserved = false;
      free = true;
  }

  ~House()
  {
      _instances--;
  }

  public void SellHouse(Customer buyer)
  {
      customer = buyer;
      sold = true;
      free = false;
  }

  public void ReserveHouse(Customer reserver)
  {
      customer = reserver;
      free = false;
      sold = false;
      reserved = true;
  }

  public void ReturnHouse()
  {
      customer = null;
      free = true;
      sold = false;
      reserved = false;
  }

  public void BuyReservedHouse(Customer buyer)
  {
      sold = true;
  }

  public bool IsFree()
  {
      return free;
  }

  public bool IsReserved()
  {
      return reserved;
  }


  public int GetHouseNumber()
  {
      return houseNumber;
  }

  public void SetCustomer(Customer buyer)
  {
      customer = buyer;
  }

  public Customer GetCustomer()
  {
      return customer;
  }

}

public class Customer
{
    private static int _instances = 0;
    private String name;
    private int id = 0;

  public Customer(String customerName)
  {
    _instances++;
    name = customerName;
    id = _instances;
  }

  public String GetName()
  {
    return name;
  }

  public int GetId()
  {
    return id;
  }
}
```

Comment: What is the `int` key of the dictionary? Why are you searching using key = 0? Can you provide more context?

Comment: @Michael I've edited my post

Comment: @YacoubMassad the int key is the street for example, street 1, street 2. using key[0] is just to provide an example of what I'm trying to achieve

Comment: Some other observations not directly relevant to your problem: 1) Consider using get-only properties instead of `GetZZZ()` methods, 2. Perhaps a dictionary isn't the best structure if you do a lot of searching in _values_ rather than _keys_.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If houses for a particular customer could be spread over many IDs then you'd need to search all value collections:

```
houseDict.SelectMany(kvp => kvp.Value)
         .Where(s => s.GetCustomer() == theCustomer)
```

This presumes that the `theCustomer` *instance* is the same instance that's in multiple value collection.  If you meed to match based on ID then you could use:

```
houseDict.SelectMany(kvp => kvp.Value)
         .Where(s => s.GetCustomer().GetId() == theCustomer.GetId())
```

Comment: Thanks for that, but what about a single ID? where a person could have multiple houses? e.g. they have 3 houses within the first key/id houseDict[0]

Comment: Either query could return multiple houses if they all have the same customer. The difference is whether or not those houses contain the same customer _instance_, or different instances with the same ID.

Comment: Sorry I should have been clearer in my last comment. so in houseDict[0] say 3 of the House array elements have John as the customer. then How would you retrieve that using lambda. without searching the whole dictionary i.e. without searching houseDict[1], houseDict[2]

Comment: @S.Bane Any of the above queries is a solution of your problem, there is no other way with your data structure (dictionary) than iterating all the entries.

Comment: @S.Bane That would just be `houseDict[0].Where(s => s.GetCustomer() == theCustomer)` which you state in your question.  I don't know what you mean by "don't know how to narrow down to the houseNumber"

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you are wanting to search the dictionary, not just the first item in the dictionary. As long as you have a `using System.Linq;` statement, you should be able to do this:

```
houseDict.ToList().Where(s => s.Value.GetCustomer() == theCustomer);
```

This will change your Dictionary into a List>, and you can use a lambda with that.